# Implementing Polling in Middle of spring Integration flow DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am writing a spring integration  DSL flow.
Which will look like below diagram.

[image: Integration flow]

As you can see in flow I need to read 1 mil entities from  database. I want o avoid reading those in single go.

I want to implement polling which will read N entities in fixed interval and send it for processing.

In the examples I read for polling, The polling is  used as the first step of the Flow. in my case I want to implement in  in middle of the flow.

Please let me know how do I implement this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger the start of some polled flow using some external stimulus, use a control bus:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63337649Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63337649Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow trigger(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "foo"))
                .transform(msg -> "@poller.start()")
                .channel("control.input")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow control() {
        return f -> f.controlBus();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "foo", e -> e
                    .id("poller")
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

}
```

Comment: @ Garry Russel Can we pass the payload of incoming message to the poller that it can use for its operation ?

Comment: If you need to transfer state from the incoming request to the JDBC poller (e.g. in the select expression) then you would need to store it in some bean in the first flow, before starting the poller.

Comment: See `QueueChannel`. So, you send a message with that data to the channel and start poller for the endpoint polling data from that channel.